# Changing locale and getting a string from other package

Tags: android, string, resources, locale

Basically I want to access some of Androids system String values. I know their location, I know how to get their value, the only issue I have is with changing locale. I want to be able to change locale and then get String values from changed locale.

My code is this:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
try {
    Resources resources = pm.getResourcesForApplication("com.android.systemui"); //package location
    bes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showingText);
    final int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.buttonChangeLanguage1:
            LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "de");
            bes.setText(R.string.testLokal);
            idS = resources.getIdentifier("battery_low_percent_format_saver_started", "string", "com.android.systemui"); //name of resource, type of resource, package of resource
            bes.setText(resources.getString(idS));
            break;
        case R.id.buttonChangeLanguage2:
            LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "sl");
            idS = resources.getIdentifier("battery_low_percent_format_saver_started", "string", "com.android.systemui");
            bes.setText(resources.getString(idS));
            break;
}catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code works I just don't get String values for different Locale, as mentioned above. I always get the values from default locale, which is English.

Class LocaleHelper I took from here: http://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/

Comment: can you try chenging locale beforegetting the resources file

Comment: Changing locale beforehand doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);`

So `bes.setText(resources.getString(R.string.testLokal));` in your case.